# Can Champions cast divine spells from scrolls?

Tags: spells, magic-items, pathfinder-2e, class

Champions have Focus Spells, and that gives them the Cast a Spell activity.
They are also trained in divine spell attacks and divine spell DCs.

Is that enough to cast spells from divine scrolls?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No

While I thought having Cast a Spell and being trained in divine spell DCs was enough, it is not.

To be able to cast a spell from a [scroll](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=720) without Trick Magic Item, it must be on your spell list:

> To Cast a Spell from a scroll, the spell must appear on your spell list

Champions do not have access to the *divine spell list* without multiclassing.

Comment: This answer is right, but anyone looking here to have their Champion cast divine scrolls and the like should look at [Trick Magic Item](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=857) - it's pretty solid on Champions since they get a Spell DC progression (and Monks, fwiw)

Comment: This comment is right, but spending 4 actions on casting a spell is rearely a good idea for a melee combatant (1 to retreive the scroll,  1 for Trick Magic Item, 2 for the spell itself) ;)